# What does 'stack' in fingerprint tell me?

Tags: android

In android's fingerprint, what information does the 'stack' part of fingerprint contains?
The 'backtrace' shows which function the app calls when the crashes happen. What does 'Stack' tell us?

Thank you.

In my example, I have '5f10868c  40157f45  /system/lib/libc.so (free+12' in my 'Stack'. My question is if I am callilng 'free' in my stack, why it is not showing up in my backtrack?

```
I/DEBUG   ( 1405): Build fingerprint: 'BRCM/java/java:4.2.2/JDQ39/523B73AA:eng/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   ( 1405): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   ( 1405): pid: 3910, tid: 3932, name: Thread-190  >>> com.mycompany.myapp <<<
I/DEBUG   ( 1405): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0000000c
D/java.hwcomposer( 1407): FBDevice::post called 32 times [0 0 2 6 19 1 0 0]
D/java.hwcomposer( 1407): FBDevice::vsync called 60 times
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     r0 00000000  r1 5faec3f8  r2 5faec400  r3 000018b0
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     r4 5de3a480  r5 5fb23880  r6 5f10871c  r7 50f30490
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     r8 5faec3f8  r9 5de3a900  sl 5f108a74  fp 5fb29898
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     ip 5e380f20  sp 5f1086c0  lr 5f96292c  pc 5f7e4258  cpsr 60000010
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     d0  69666e6f635f7866  d1  6a6f72703c22206e
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     d2  746f6f7220746365  d3  672f617461642f3e
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     d4  000003174445c000  d5  43f000004445c000
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     d6  3f530fb43a03126f  d7  3f638e393f52eeef
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     d16 0000000000000000  d17 3fe0000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     d18 0000000000000000  d19 3fa55553e1053a42
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     d20 3fe6a09e68ca0fb9  d21 bf29c8b65c055bdd
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     d22 8000000000000000  d23 c038000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     d24 4038000000000000  d25 8000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     d26 3ff0000000000000  d27 0000004800000048
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     d28 0000000200000003  d29 0000000000000001
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     scr 20000093
I/DEBUG   ( 1405): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1405): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     #00  pc 000ed258  /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/libs/libapp.so (Game::PostInitRefreshGFX()+140)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     #01  pc 000eda88  /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/libs/libapp.so (Game::PostInit()+1256)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     #02  pc 000e797c  /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/libs/libapp.so (GameState::UpdateCurrentState()+108)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     #03  pc 000e7b28  /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/libs/libapp.so (Game::FrameUpdate()+196)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     #04  pc 000e8000  /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/libs/libapp.so (Game::OnUpdate()+560)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     #05  pc 000de5e4  /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/libs/libapp.so (appUpdate+300)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     #06  pc 0001e290  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     #07  pc 0004d471  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+396)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     #08  pc 00038c05  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCheckCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+8)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     #09  pc 000276a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     #10  pc 0002b57c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     #11  pc 0005fc91  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     #12  pc 0005fcbb  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     #13  pc 00054837  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     #14  pc 0000e408  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     #15  pc 0000daf4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+160)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1405): stack:
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108680  40196da4  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108684  5f108714  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108688  40196408  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10868c  40157f45  /system/lib/libc.so (free+12)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108690  40196408  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108694  40168251  /system/lib/libc.so (fclose+140)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108698  5f1086bc  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10869c  800aa4bb  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1086a0  5f1086bc  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1086a4  5de3a480  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1086a8  5fb23880  /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/libs/libapp.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1086ac  5f10871c  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1086b0  50f30490  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1086b4  5faec3f8  /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/libs/libapp.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1086b8  df0027ad  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1086bc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     #00  5f1086c0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1086c4  00000006  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1086c8  5faf31e8  /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/libs/libapp.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1086cc  5faf31e8  /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/libs/libapp.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1086d0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1086d4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1086d8  5faf0000  /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/libs/libapp.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1086dc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1086e0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1086e4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1086e8  5d3f7480  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1086ec  5d3f7480  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1086f0  5d9af4c4  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1086f4  00000013  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1086f8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1086fc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108700  ffffffff  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108704  5de37e00  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108708  5de37e00  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10870c  5d9af7a4  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108710  00000005  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108714  5faf31e8  /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/libs/libapp.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108718  5faf31e8  /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/libs/libapp.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10871c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108720  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108724  5de37df0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108728  5de37df0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10872c  5d9af784  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108730  00000007  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108734  5de37de0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108738  5de37de0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10873c  5d9af764  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108740  0000000b  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108744  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108748  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10874c  5fb23880  /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/libs/libapp.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108750  5de3a480  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108754  000013e0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108758  5de3a900  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10875c  5f108a84  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108760  5d3f7468  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108764  5f108a74  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108768  5f108ac4  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10876c  5f7e4a8c  /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/libs/libapp.so (Game::PostInit()+1260)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     #01  5f108770  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108774  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108778  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10877c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108780  5f108aa4  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108784  00000c98  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108788  40015ba0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10878c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108790  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108794  5f108ab4  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108798  00000638  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10879c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1087a0  c0000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1087a4  00000c00  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1087a8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1087ac  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1087b0  00000c08  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1087b4  4015c3f3  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc+5170)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1087b8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1087bc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1087c0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1087c4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1087c8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1087cc  5c4be810  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1087d0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1087d4  40015448  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1087d8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1087dc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1087e0  800aa4bb  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1087e4  4058b213  /system/lib/libEGL.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1087e8  00000013  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1087ec  4015c3f3  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc+5170)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1087f0  00000c00  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1087f4  5f9ab210  /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/libs/libapp.so (std::vector<vox::PriorityBank, vox::SAllocator<vox::PriorityBank, (vox::VoxMemHint)0> >::reserve(unsigned int)+496)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1087f8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1087fc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108800  5c6c3008  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108804  5c6c3bf0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108808  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10880c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108810  40015448  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108814  5d9a5fd4  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108818  5d9a60b0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10881c  5d9a6090  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108820  5c130321  /system/lib/libuip.so (HwMemAllocatorImpl::virt2phys(unsigned int&, void const*))
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108824  5c12edc1  /system/lib/libuip.so (HwMemBlock::handleLock(unsigned int&, void*&, unsigned int&))
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108828  5de2d6c8  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10882c  5c4fe000  anon_inode:dmabuf
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108830  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108834  5c1303b3  /system/lib/libuip.so (HwMemAllocatorImpl::virt2phys(unsigned int&, void const*)+146)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108838  00000208  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10883c  5f10888c  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108840  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108844  80d80000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108848  00080000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10884c  800aa4bb  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108850  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108854  5c8ee588  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108858  40072a3d  /system/lib/hw/gralloc.java.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10885c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108860  5c252efc  anon_inode:dmabuf
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108864  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108868  00000001  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10886c  5f1088c0  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108870  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108874  5c12f9cd  /system/lib/libuip.so (mem_lock_multiple+188)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108878  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10887c  5f1088ac  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108880  5c14ddc4  /system/lib/libuip.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108884  5c14dd38  /system/lib/libuip.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108888  5f108900  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10888c  81200000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108890  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108894  5de2d770  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108898  5f108978  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10889c  5c252e74  anon_inode:dmabuf
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1088a0  00000001  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1088a4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1088a8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1088ac  5de2d770  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1088b0  5f108978  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1088b4  5ff453c5  /system/lib/egl/libGLES_java.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1088b8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1088bc  00008000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1088c0  5ec0b034  /dev/binder
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1088c4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1088c8  5ec0b0e0  /dev/binder
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1088cc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1088d0  5f1088fc  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1088d4  00007722  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1088d8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1088dc  400fe6f3  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::ProcessState::self()+110)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1088e0  5de220e8  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1088e4  5f1088fc  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1088e8  5f108a78  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1088ec  400f8207  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::sp<android::IPermissionController>::~sp()+22)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1088f0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1088f4  400fcc05  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::Parcel::releaseObjects()+54)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1088f8  5f108a78  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1088fc  5cfe81e8  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108900  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108904  5f108a78  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108908  000000b8  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10890c  00000002  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108910  c0000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108914  00000010  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108918  c0000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10891c  00000010  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108920  5c77f000  anon_inode:dmabuf
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108924  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108928  0000001b  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10892c  4015c3f3  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc+5170)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108930  00010008  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108934  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108938  0001000b  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10893c  5dcff378  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108940  5c14de54  /system/lib/libuip.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108944  5d900fd0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108948  5c77f000  anon_inode:dmabuf
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10894c  5c8ee588  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108950  5c14dd3c  /system/lib/libuip.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108954  00000001  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108958  00000044  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10895c  5d901dc8  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108960  000c3000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108964  40157f31  /system/lib/libc.so (malloc+12)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108968  5d901610  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10896c  4028f8ef  /system/lib/libstdc++.so (operator new(unsigned int)+6)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108970  5d901610  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108974  5c12fac9  /system/lib/libuip.so (rtos_add_mapping+188)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108978  00000045  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10897c  81500000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108980  5d901e5c  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108984  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108988  5d901dc8  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10898c  0000001a  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108990  5d901dd0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108994  5d901dc8  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108998  5c8ee5a0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f10899c  00000002  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1089a0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1089a4  400731c3  /system/lib/hw/gralloc.java.so (gralloc_register_buffer(gralloc_module_t const*, native_handle const*)+82)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1089a8  00000044  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1089ac  5d901dc8  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1089b0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1089b4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1089b8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1089bc  4010e477  /system/lib/libui.so (android::GraphicBufferMapper::registerBuffer(native_handle const*)+74)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1089c0  5ec0b034  /dev/binder
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1089c4  40157f31  /system/lib/libc.so (malloc+12)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1089c8  00000002  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1089cc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1089d0  000000b8  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1089d4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1089d8  5f108a04  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1089dc  00007722  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1089e0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1089e4  400fe6f3  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::ProcessState::self()+110)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1089e8  c0000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1089ec  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1089f0  5f108a48  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1089f4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1089f8  5f108b08  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f1089fc  4015c843  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+34)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a00  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a04  5f108a48  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a08  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a0c  5f108b08  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a10  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a14  5f108a64  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a18  00000001  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a1c  5f108a63  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a20  5c243000  anon_inode:dmabuf
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a24  5ff47f9b  /system/lib/egl/libGLES_java.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a28  00000001  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a2c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a30  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a34  5ff4870b  /system/lib/egl/libGLES_java.so (khrn_nmem_alloc+402)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a38  5c243000  anon_inode:dmabuf
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a3c  00000188  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a40  5c243000  anon_inode:dmabuf
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a44  5f108a64  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a48  5ffeb75c  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a4c  5f108a64  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a50  5d9b0c70  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a54  00000008  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a58  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a5c  5ffeb75c  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a60  5f108afc  [stack:3932]
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a64  00000001  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a68  00000001  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a6c  5d9b0c50  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a70  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a74  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a78  5d9b0c70  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a7c  5ff76341  /system/lib/egl/libGLES_java.so (glxx_hw_start_frame_internal+250)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a80  0001a418  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a84  5d3f7480  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a88  5d3f7480  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a8c  5d9af4c4  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a90  00000013  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a94  5de3ab60  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a98  5de3ab60  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108a9c  5d9af464  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108aa0  0000000a  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108aa4  5de3ac58  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108aa8  5de3ac58  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108aac  5d9af424  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108ab0  00000007  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108ab4  5d9afc90  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108ab8  5d9afc90  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108abc  5d9af444  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108ac0  00000005  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108ac4  5c8ee5a0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108ac8  5c8ee5a0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108acc  5dfba394  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108ad0  00000001  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108ad4  5c44ee40  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108ad8  5c44ee40  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108adc  5d9af204  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108ae0  00000006  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108ae4  5c8ee5a0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108ae8  5c8ee5a0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108aec  5dfba394  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108af0  00000001  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108af4  5d0d28a0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108af8  5d0d28a0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108afc  5dfba374  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b00  00000007  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b04  40015b80  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b08  40015b80  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b0c  5dfba354  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b10  00000014  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b14  40015b68  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b18  40015b68  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b1c  5dfba334  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b20  00000010  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b24  40015b48  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b28  40015b48  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b2c  5dfba314  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b30  00000014  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b34  40015b28  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b38  40015b28  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b3c  5dfba2f4  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b40  00000014  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b44  5d9afcb0  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b48  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b4c  5de2da88  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b50  00004500  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b54  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b58  6006dd0c  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b5c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b60  fffffffe  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b64  40176d31  /system/lib/libc.so (sem_wait+36)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b68  6006dd0c  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b6c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b70  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b74  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b78  5d9ab430  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b7c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b80  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b84  50f2d008  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b88  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b8c  5ff52d4f  /system/lib/egl/libGLES_java.so (glUseProgram_impl_20+206)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b90  5ff52c81  /system/lib/egl/libGLES_java.so (glUseProgram_impl_20)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b94  800aa4bb  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b98  00000c94  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108b9c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108ba0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108ba4  5fb2bd52  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108ba8  5fb23880  /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/libs/libapp.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108bac  000004f4  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108bb0  000016d8  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108bb4  00000013  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108bb8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108bbc  4c72b4f1  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108bc0  00000141  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108bc4  5f7de980  /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/libs/libapp.so (GameState::UpdateCurrentState()+112)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     #02  5f108bc8  5de3a480  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108bcc  5fb23880  /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/libs/libapp.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108bd0  00000001  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108bd4  ffffff1f  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108bd8  00000013  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):          5f108bdc  5f7deb2c  /data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/libs/libapp.so (Game::FrameUpdate()+200)
I/DEBUG   ( 1405): 
I/DEBUG   ( 1405): memory near r1:
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     5faec3d8 6f5f6e61 74737475 69646e61 705f676e  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     5faec3e8 6f667265 6e616d72 772e6563 00007661  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     5faec3f8 544e4954 00004e49 2d2d2d2d 202d2d2d  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     5faec408 6c616373 66252065 00000000 2d2d2d2d  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     5faec418 202d2d2d 63735f6d 6e656572 74646957  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     5faec428 2e252068 6d206630 7263735f 486e6565  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     5faec438 68676965 2e252074 00006630 2d2d2d2d  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     5faec448 202d2d2d 52786667 20576665 66302e25  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     5faec458 78666720 48666552 302e2520 00000066  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     5faec468 4f5f4c47 645f5345 68747065 7865745f  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     5faec478 65727574 00000000 455f4c47 645f5458  
I/DEBUG   ( 1405):     5faec488 68747065 7865745f 65727574 00000000
```

Comment: I would imagine it tells you what is in the stack.

Comment: stack shows the content of the program stack at the time of the crash.  If you call functionBlammo() and it returns then you call functionHootBerry() and the crash happens, then the stack will contain a call to functionHootBerry() but not a call to functionBlammo() because blammo already returned (and is no longer represented on the stack).